# File Permission Errors

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, file-permissions

Recently I have been receiving lots of File Permission Errors when saving documents. I have searched the internet endlessly and have still not found a solution.

Sometimes, when I save from Word (2010) I get this error:

```
Word cannot complete the save due to a file permission error.
```

Then I can retry, it asks me to overwrite the old file and it works.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate.

It is also happening in other applications. Such as Photoshop (CS5), again I resave and overwrite and it works.

I get a problem in iTunes too:

```
The iTunes Library file cannot be saved. An unknown error has occurred
```

This is IMMENSELY annoying so any help is appreciated!

Comment: More information needed. Where are you trying to save to? What are the permissions assigned to that location?

Comment: How do I show you the permissions?

Comment: Some Security Softwares can cause this issue, disable or uninstall the security software, see if the error stops.

Comment: Where do you save these files? USB drive?

Comment: @Moab, I am inclined to agree that this sounds like antivirus behaviour. I'd remove whatever AV is installed and see if the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a system restore and seeing if you still get the same errors? Perhaps rolling it back may help.

Comment: This is a challenge if OP doesn't know when exactly the problem started, versus which restore point to use.